# Why is there no * in front of delegate declaration?

Tags: iphone, delegates, protocols, declaration, standards-compliance

I just noticed there is no * in front of the declaration for a delegate ...

I did something like this :

```
@protocol NavBarHiddenDelegate;


@interface AsyncImageView : UIView {

    NSURLConnection* connection;
    NSMutableData* data;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator;

    id <NavBarHiddenDelegate> delegate;

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <NavBarHiddenDelegate> delegate;

- (id)initWithUrl:(NSString*)url;

@end


@protocol NavBarHiddenDelegate 

- (void)hideNavBar;

@end
```

It works perfectly well but as I am used to always but a * in front of objects I declare, why not for this one ?!?

Thank you,

Gotye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with delegates.

The type `id` is different, for historical reasons; think of it as `any-object *`. Whenever you write `id`, there is no `*`.

If there were a single root class `Object` for all Objective-C objects then you could imagine that `typedef Object * id;` — but there isn't, so `id` is different (well, actually, it's defined as something like `struct objc_object *` if I recall correctly, but you shouldn't worry about that implementation-detail-with-respect-to-this-level).

Answer (score 1):

Because `id` already has its implicit `*`. If you ignore the protocol restriction then

```
id <NavBarHiddenDelegate> delegate;
```

becomes

```
id delegate;
```

which obviously doesn't need a `*`. BTW, if the protocol is put on an ObjC type then you need the `*`, e.g.

```
XXViewController<NavBarHiddenDelegate>* delegate;
```